# Alternative for creating list of different length vectors in R

Tags: r, list, for-loop, nested-loops

I am very new in R and I am trying to create a list of different size vectors using nested for loop.
Specifically I am working with a m*4 data frame that represents pedestrians' trajectories as they are recorded in camera. The first column is called "Time" and denotes the number of the frame, second and third columns denote agent's coordinates (X and Y respectively) and the fourth column is the pedestrian ID.

Trying to compute for each pedestrian (in each video frame) how many are the agents that are close to him (to the "examined" pedestrian), I came up with the below nested loop

```
for (i in 1:length(Nframe){
 for (ii in 1:length(NPed_id)){
  newdata1 <- subset(newdata,newdata$`Time (ms)`== Nframe[i])
  real_Density[ii] = sum(newdata1$X<(newdata1$X[ii]+3000)&newdata1$X>(newdata1$X[ii]-3000)&newdata1$Y<(newdata1$Y[ii]+3000)&newdata1$Y>(newdata1$Y[ii]-3000)&newdata1$`Time (ms)`==Nframe[i])
  real_Density <- real_Density[!is.na(real_Density)]
  Real_Density[[i]] <- real_Density
 }
}
```

I know that for loops is not the most suitable way in R but I cannot think of anything else. Are there any suggestions?